# Find the derivative of the following function: $\displaystyle y(x) = (\ln{(2 x)})^{5 x}, \quad x> \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Find the derivative of the following function.

$$\displaystyle y(x) = (\ln{(2 x)})^{5 x}, \quad x> \frac{1}{2}$$

So the [answer given by wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20%28ln%282x%29%29%5E%285x%29) seems to be correct:

$$5 \ln^{(5 x-1)}(2 x) (\ln(2 x) \cdot \ln(\ln(2 x))+1)$$

But whence do these $(\ln(2 x) \ln(\ln(2 x))+1)$ come?

Shouldn't there be fractions as derivative of $\ln x = \frac{1}{x}$?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a function of the form $y = f(x)^{g(x)}$, it is usually a good idea to use logarithmic differentiation:  $$\log y = g(x) \log f(x),$$ hence $$\frac{d}{dx} [ \log y ] = \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ g(x) \log f(x) \right],$$ and $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)^{g(x)} \left( \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{dg}{dx} \log f(x) \right).$$  So, in your case, $f(x) = \log 2x$ and $g(x) = 5x$, so we have $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{2x} \cdot 2 = \frac{1}{x},$$ and $$\frac{dg}{dx} = 5,$$ therefore after minor simplifications, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (\log 2x)^{5x} \left( \frac{5}{\log 2x} + 5 \log (\log 2x) \right).$$  The only additional step that was done was to put the fractions over a common denominator of $\log 2x$ and factoring:  $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 5 (\log 2x)^{5x-1} (1 + (\log 2x) \log (\log 2x)).$$

Comment: That's a great technique, using the logarithmic derivative.

Comment: @heropup I don't understand, d/dx[logy]???? why is it not dy/dx? On the left you have log of y!!!! And then what happens to that 1/y???

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$.  If I wrote $\frac{d}{dx}[y(x)]$, what does that mean?

Comment: And so, by the chain rule, for differentiable functions $h(x)$ and $k(x)$, what is $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ h(k(x)) \right]?$$  What if $h(x) = \log x$ and $k(x) = y(x)$?  Then that would be $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \log y(x) \right].$$

Comment: well you wrote: 1/y dy/dx where does it go afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Great problem. Okay, it seems you understand that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}a^{x}=a^{x}ln(a)$$

But the Chain Rule gets tricky on this problem because you effectively have a function of two variables:

$$f(x,a)\equiv a^{5x}$$
where 
$$a(x)\equiv ln(2x)$$
and so the Chain Rule yields:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,a(x))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dx}$$

The partial derivatives wrt a, x are respectively at constant x, a.

So that applied to your problem as follows:

$$f(x)\equiv(ln(2x))^{5x}$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=(ln(2x))^{5x}ln(ln(2x))+5x(ln(2x))^{5x-1}\frac{d}{dx}ln(2x)$$

That's how your troubling $\frac{1}{x}$ will get cancelled. I'll let you handle the algebra from there.

Comment: I don't get it, how did you get a(x)=ln(2x) from f(x,a)≡a^5x??

Comment: @Jack  No, the 3rd eqn does come FROM the 2nd eqn. I created a(x) in order to break the OP's equation down into simpler parts.  If you combine those two equations, you get the OP's equations back.  I will edit a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jack  Does that help?

Comment: yeah, but I don't understand what these mean and where they come from: ∂f/∂x+∂f/∂a da/dx.Like this doesn't look like chain rule, in chain rule you should have two multiples, right? In here you simply have something in the power of 5x.

Comment: there's also a formula for some chain rule: $f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$? Why can't it be applied here?

Comment: So what you do is first you say a(x) = ln2x, u = a(x)$u^{5x} = lnu \cdot u^{5x}$, substituting back $ lna(x) \cdot a(x)^{5x}$ -> $ ln ln(2x) \cdot (ln2x)^{5x}$

Comment: @Jack  I am applying the chain rule, but you have to remember that in this example f depends on g(x) and on x directly.  If f didn't depend on x, then the general chain rule in my answer would reduce to the simpler chain rule you posts.  You're in good company making that error though, I've caught several scientists making it.   :-)